# Upload a file in a directory using C# allow to view it

Tags: c#, user-interface, file-upload, directory

I am new to C#. How can i possible upload a file like pdf and image in a particular folder using C# windows gui? Do i need to add library for it to work in viewing it directly to the gui program? Also, i need to allow the user to upload multiple files. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what exactly you want to do?

Comment: A couple of things: What did you try so far? Is there a specific problem you're stuck with? To where do you want to upload your files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to browse and display picture inside a picture box on your windows form you can try something like this:

**Design of the form:**

[image: Windows form design]

**Code:**

```
public PictureDisplay()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog newDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (newDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            picBoxDisplay.Load(newDialog.FileName);
            picBoxDisplay.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong file type!", "Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Code opens file dialog and if you choose a file of image type it's displayed to fit into a picture box while maintaining resolution ratio. If any other type is chosen *MessageBox* pops and makes you aware of an error.

**Results:**

[image: App start]
[image: App browse]
[image: App image loaded]

Hopefully it covers the image upload to GUI part. For any further help, please explain the question better, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open file png/*.*
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

View Pictures
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please copy and paste the relevant data from the links into your answer, as in the future the links may become broken and the answer will not be clear.